# Columnists sometimes lay an egg, but Martin has laid an ostrich omelette. (why means 'fail'?)

Tags: idioms

> Columnists sometimes lay an egg, but Martin has laid an ostrich omelette.

Q1. why 'lay an egg' means 'fail'?

Q2. what's the meaning of 'lay an ostrich omelette'?

Comment: I think it's a rather overstretched attempt an a pun - riffing off [a pretty "dated" idiomatic usage](https://grammarist.com/idiom/lay-an-egg/#:~:text=To%20lay%20an%20egg%20means,zero%20is%20a%20goose%20egg.&text=Related%20phrases%20are%20lays%20an,an%20egg%2C%20laying%20an%20egg.) anyway.

Answer (score 4):

##### Where did this idiom come from?

According to [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lay+an+egg), which cites *The Dictionary of Clichés* by Christine Ammer, this idiom has separate origins in British and American dialects.

> In Britain this term comes from cricket, where a player or team failing to score has, since the mid-nineteenth century, been said to get a duck’s egg (meaning 0, or zero). In America the term appeared in the latter part of the nineteenth century in vaudeville and theater, similarly signifying a flop of a performance. It was transferred to other arenas by the early twentieth century, and fittingly, a headline in Variety (the American chronicle of show business at the time) read, in October 1929, “Wall Street Lays An Egg.”

##### What's that about ostriches and omelettes?

Ostrich eggs are big. [Very big](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bushmen_drinkingwater.jpg). And you can't have an omelette without breaking the egg. So, whatever Martin did, it was a much bigger and fail-y failure than you would usually expect from a columnist.